# What are you the most excited about in the new versions of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A recent new jQuery version has been released, the jQuery v1.4. You can read all about it [here](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14). It allows you to do some pretty neat stuff such as:

```
$("div.test").bind({
  click: function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
  },
  mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).addClass("inside");
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).removeClass("inside");
  }
});
```

**What do you like the most about this new version? What is the thing that made you go "FINALLY!"?**

---

*Added a bounty to get more feedback and accept an answer*

Comment: definitely excited, not exited.

Comment: That's what cw is for :)

Comment: @closers: I think it's a real question, it allows us to share what will be the next step of jQuery, of widely used framework here on SO. For instance I missed the part about delay() and I'm glad that Doug reminded me of it ! Plus it's cw, come on

Comment: I second marcgg. I can't understand why people are trying to close it. It sounds like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: I third marcgg (is it correct to say that? :P) , If he already have it as a community wiki, he had -pretty much- put the question on the super Untouchable safe side (SUSS), the question can be argumentative, subjective and a poll..and still be safe from closing or deleting!

Comment: Just something about the bounty - will the winner still get the bounty points even if it is a Community Wiki question?

Comment: @adhip: I think so. You could ask that on meta

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Best feature in my opinion is allowing functions in setters:

```
jQuery('li.selected').html(function(i, li) {
   return "<strong>" + li + "</strong>";
});
```

A lot of code that required $.each can be removed now.

Comment: Could that also be `jQuery('li.selected').wrapInner(<strong />)`

Comment: see my comment on the answer bellow

Answer (score 58):

Believe it or not, the "FINALLY" moment for me was the addition of [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$("#notice").slideDown('500').delay(4000).slideUp('500'); // = Pure awesome :)
```

Comment: Isn't that just a wrapper for `setTimeout`?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, The fact that you can use it in method chaining like the example above though is a huge plus.

Comment: This should have been the question accepted. I don't know what went wrong ?

Comment: Ok this is the problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18944/in-a-bounty-scenario-can-an-answer-from-before-the-bounty-be-automatically-accep ... Sorry about that :\

Comment: @marcgg No worries. I actually read that Meta question (or a similar one) and understood it to mean you would manually have to pick a winner, not that it would auto accept the highest entry *since* the bounty started... LOL. Oh well :)

Answer (score 44):

The ability to create elements on the fly in a more terse manner, by passing all attributes as the second argument to `jQuery()`:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    mouseenter: function() {
        // do stuff
    },
    html: jQuery('<a/>', {
        href: 'http://google.com',
        click: function() {
            // do stuff
        }
    })
});
```

All non-attribute properties map to the corresponding jQuery method. So having `html` there will call `.html()` and having `click` will bind a new `click` event via `.click()`...

Comment: I always felt so torn between writing the raw HTML and calling attr() on the element after creation. This is much better :)

Comment: Why is `$('<div/>', { id: 'foo' })` better than `$('<div id="foo"/>')`? They both work just fine, and the latter is shorter and easier to read and write. (Honest question; I really have no idea!)

Comment: Mathias, the point is that values of attributes are often needed to be calculated. Compare: `$('<div id="' + calcId() + '"/>')` and `$('<div/>', { id : calcId() })`

Answer (score 18):

I don't really have a favorite, here's an overview of 15 new features for those who don't know what this is all about:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-1-4-released-the-15-new-features-you-must-know/

Answer (score 17):

I am a speed freak so any speed improvement is always welcomed by me

Comment: +1'd for the incredibly speed improvements in 1.4!!!

Comment: In particular `find` and `append` were amazing for me.

Answer (score 12):

For me it was this:

> "All Events Can Be Live Events"
>
> "We’re very proud to count some
>   addtional events amongst those
>   supported by live(). 1.4 introduces
>   cross-browser support for change,
>   submit, focusin, focusout, mouseenter,
>   and mouseleave via the event
>   delegation in .live()."

I've been waiting for this on the change event for ages!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you give an example ?

Comment: The `live` function binds an event to a "selector", so that if you create new elements that match the selector, they get the event too. Previously it only worked with a handful of events like `click` and `mouseover`. Now it works for practically every event.

Answer (score 6):

Well the performance improvements are of course something I appreciate, but I guess I can't say it's a "finally" since it's something that's subject to constant improvement :) The DOM-building (Quick Element Construction) syntax looks really convenient, and the `detach` method also looks quite usable: it allows you to temporarily remove an object from the DOM, but keeps all the handlers assigned to it, so that it'll work just the same way, when reinserted.

I guess there's not so much a lot of things that I've been missing, but now that these new features are out there, there's a bunch that I'm anxious to start using :)

Answer (score 6):

Event delegation for focus and bubble events:

- http://api.jquery.com/focusin/
- http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 4):

I really like delay() and detach() the most, to be honest. The performance improvements are a huge plus as well but delay() is probably the single most amazing part of it. Simple but ultra useful. No more setTimeouts().

Answer (score 3):

It has been very modular since 1.3+.  For example, when you don't need the ajax library, it is nice to build without it.  Keep file sizes down.

Answer (score 3):

Call me crazy, but just the added number of tests gives me a warm fuzzy feeling.  I almost want to upvote every answer :)_

Answer (score 3):

I think unwrap() is simple, elegant, and you get an innerHTML present at the end!

> The new unwrap method will take the
>   children of a given parent and replace
>   said parent with them. Like so:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>this</p> <p>is</p> <p>fun</p>
    </div>
</body>

$('div').unwrap();

<body>
   <p>this</p> <p>is</p> <p>fun</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.proxy()
```

To make sure that *this* always means *this* rather than *that*...

Example from [here](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/blog/16-understanding-jquery-1-4-s-proxy-method)

```
MyModule = function() {
  this.$div = $('#testdiv');
  this.myString = "Hi! I'm an object property!";

  this.$div.click($.proxy(this.handleClick, this));
};

MyModule.prototype.handleClick = function() {
  console.log(this.myString); // Hi! I'm an object property!
};

var m = new MyModule();
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it's the ability to now write event handlers with the `live()` handler. I know that `live` was present in the last version (1.3.2) also, but it wasn't fully supported.

This makes the code infinitely simpler especially if you have most of the DOM being created on the fly or via Ajax requests.

More about `live` here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

live() calls with events such as change is a big one for me. I have been wanting this for sometime now.