# hiding a div with certain time bound

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to hide a div after some time period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426304/how-to-hide-a-div-after-some-time-period)

i need to hide a div (like mail sent successfull in gmail)after certain time period when i reload the page ? any body please help me by giving codes..

Comment: I am sooo tempted to tag this `plz-send-teh-codez` :)

Comment: do you mean "after certain time period **or** when i reload the page" ?

Comment: Folks, don't waste your time on this. The same guy asked the same question an hour ago, received *extensive* help by two people in the comments but didn't get anything he could copy+paste, so he decided to ask the same question again. What the f****. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426304/how-to-hide-a-div-after-some-time-period

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timePeriodInMs = 4000;

setTimeout(function() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none"; 
}, 
timePeriodInMs);
```

Comment: If I read him correctly, he wants persistence across page reloads.

Comment: Folks, don't waste your time on this question. See my comment to the question above.

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('messageID').style.display = 'none';
}, 5000);  //5secs
```

Comment: If I read him correctly, he wants persistence across page reloads.

Comment: @Pekka: he says like gmail, in gmail, if we reload the page just after sending a mail, the "mail sent" notice does not persist.

Comment: @nvl true, but he also says `after certain time period when i reload the page ? `

Comment: may be he missed " **or** " ? :)

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 /*$(document).ready(function(){
     window.setTimeout(function(){
         $('#deletesucess').hide();
     }, 10000 /* delay time in milliseconds 
 });*/
setTimeout('$("#deletesucess").hide()',1500);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="deletesucess" >
hiiiiiiiiiii
</div>
</body>
</html> not working pekka

Comment: Folks, don't waste your time on this question. See my comment to the question above.

Comment: got solution guys:-stackoverflow.com/questions/2426304/how-to-hide-a-div-after-some-time-period.... thanks for your kind support. regards, rag

Answer (score 2):

If you want the element to disappear after a certain time, **regardless of page reloads** (that's the way I read your question), you would have to work with cookies.

- You would have to set a cookie with the starting point
- You would have to execute a JavaScript function on page load that compares the time set in the cookie with the current time, and shows/hides the element accordingly.
- For a perfect solution, you would additionally implement a timer that compares the current date to the date in the cookie every, say, half-second, and hides the element when the time has been reached.

Using a framework like JQuery is certainly a good idea for this.

Comment: :)
pekka pls give a solution.if anythng i need to clarify with my question pls  ask me

Comment: @rag it is rude in the *extreme* to open a question, receive *extensive* support there much beyond normal level, and then when no reaction comes for 20 minutes to open *the same question again*. You are showing zero respect for your fellow programmers' time and attention - most of whom have work to do - and you can be sure I will not be putting one minute into your questions again. Go learn it yourself.

Comment: pekka i have tried it in javascript becuase i need to find eithr der should be  solution..

Comment: @rag then go and hire somebody to solve it for you.

Comment: ok pekka i let me analyse those supports...thanks guys am leavng thanks pekka..

Comment: pekka i got solution from my jquery posts...hi:)

thanks&regards :rag

Answer (score 1):

You may use `setTimeout` to delay a function's execution:

```
window.setTimeout(doSomething, 1000); // 1000ms == 1 second
```

To hide an element, you may set its `display` property to `none`:

```
var element = document.getElementById('foo');

function doSomething() {
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: If I read him correctly, he wants persistence across page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the `setTimeout( expression, timeout );` where you need to give it an `expression` to run after the `timeout` in milliseconds that you allocate to it. then you would do `element.style.display="none"`

ex:

```
setTimeout( function(){element.style.display="none"}, 4000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add jquery to your html document
2. add script tag to head of your document containing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $('#id-of-div').hide();
        }, 10000 /* delay time in milliseconds */
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#deletesucess').delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
//setTimeout('$("#deletesucess").hide()',1500);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="deletesucess" >
hiiiiiiiiiii
</div>
</body>
</html>
i have tried this kris but not working

Comment: @rag have you added JQuery to the document?

Comment: That makes me think jquery didn't actually load for that page, or that your documents parse tree is somehow broken. what does the javascript console say? (firebug or webkit inspector available?)

Comment: One does not need a whole 26kb JQuery library to do this. What if he does not want a to use a library? What if he uses Mootools?

Comment: and tried ur  $(document).ready(function(){
     window.setTimeout(function(){
         $('#id-of-div').hide();
     }, 10000 /* delay time in milliseconds */
 }); ------------->not working

Comment: @Jonathan, then he should disregard my answer and go with another solution of the readily available ones.

Comment: Folks, don't waste your time on this guy. See my comment to the question above.

Comment: Thats because he/she expects you to install JQuery just to do this.

Comment: /jqury/jquery-1.4.2.min.js:77Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and timehidediv.php:12Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } are the errors

Comment: you have a typo somewhere before line 13 of the html output

Comment: Its because he made no mention of using JQuery so I don't see it as a valid answer.

Comment: got solution guys:-stackoverflow.com/questions/2426304/how-to-hide-a-div-after-some-time-period....
thanks for your kind support.
regards,
rag

Comment: jQuery not necessary for this one.

Comment: @Harlin: ofcourse not and nowadays it would be pretty weird to add jquery to anything for almost any reason but the landscape was very different in 2010, jquery was a great equalizer that was almost essential to support more than one browser at a time.