# Search for contents inside a website

Tags: php, html, xml

Anybody please give some useful links on this topic.i need to create a content search for my website.. i have tried  google but not get useful materials on this topic...please help me

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=search+engine+website+php

Comment: Give some use full things Yacoby,instead doing of minus vote doesn't give any solution...

Comment: Yacoby edited out a typo from your question, he didn't necessarily cast the downvote.

Comment: I think time spent on trying to help this guy is wasted. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426659/hiding-a-div-with-certain-time-bound

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> have tried google but not get useful materials on this topic

Have you tried Google?

Seriously, [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/) is very easy to set up and does not require any PHP programming. It doesn't integrate 100% in your site's design but works well.

Comment: please give one example of the site which is using this type of search..(may be i think this one allows the google itself to seacrh for our webcontent right?)

Comment: @Rag stack Overflow, for example, uses it for advanced search.

Comment: @rag why? What kind of support are you expecting?

Answer (score 6):

While google custom search **is a good solution**, and **you didn't give much information**, a [simple google search](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+search+engines) **does** turn up some good results:

[Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/), which I think I used *years* ago:

> Sphider is a lightweight web spider and search engine written in PHP, using MySQL as its back end database. It is a great tool for adding search functionality to your web site or building your custom search engine. Sphider is small, easy to set up and modify, and is used in thousands of websites across the world.

[PhpDig](http://www.phpdig.net/) (on the 2nd page of results, so it was hard to find), I know I've used this before, another 'installable' php based search engine:

> PhpDig is a web spider and search engine written in PHP, using a MySQL database and flat file support. PhpDig builds a glossary with words found in indexed pages. On a search query, it displays a result page containing the search keys, ranked by occurrence.

[Sphinx + PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/), an older article, I can't really speak to how well it fits your needs, but it might be a good place to start if you don't want to use a ready made script:

> While Google and its ilk are virtually omniscient, the Web's mighty search engines aren't well suited to every site. If your site content is highly specialized or distinctly categorized, use Sphinx and PHP to create a finely tuned local search system.

[About's PHP Search Tutorial](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_search.htm), certianlly nothing special (it's quite the simplification of a search engine), but another place to start if you want to write it yourself:

> Our search engine tutorial assumes that all the data you want to be searchable is stored in your MySQL database. It will not have any fancy algorithms - just a simple LIKE query, but it will work for basic searching and give you a jumping off point to make a more complex searching system.

Of course, **more information would mean better answers**.