# Is it possible to assign time span to background-image of DIV

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to assign time span to background-image of DIV ?

Do you guys know if I can do it with jQuery or not ? I want first image to stay 20 seconds and second image to stay 5 seconds. So they should change each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fadeToggle like this http://jsfiddle.net/cwsUF/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this in your document ready...

```
setTimeout("ChangeToBlue();", 20000);
```

Then... the function...

```
function ChangeToBlue()
{
    $("#background").css("background-color", "blue");
}
```

I'm setting the background to a color... but same idea.  If you want it to switch back and forth, set another timeout in the function.