# Rails 'render' function rendering something for short duration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I got

```
render :text => "Some text"
```

what I really need is something like this

```
render :text => "Some text", :duration => 5000
```

The "some text" will be rendered for a short duration of time and then it will disappear.

If it is not possible, can I use `:alert` tag for the same thing, and how exactly?

Comment: ... This would need to be handled via JavaScript, on the client side. You could generate that JS via normal Rails mechanisms, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider that you are using HTTP, which is stateless. This means: There is NO connection between client and server. It's always just:

- Client: Hello server, please give me `http://.../someResource`
- Server: Here it is

Every time the client asks for a resource the server cannot remember that he was there before (at least in plain strict HTTP). Then there came people and invented Sessions and Cookies, but that's a different story.

What I wanted to say: The server can ONLY send the requested resource and after this is done he doesn't know that there was a client and requested something.

You have only one choice for dynamic behaviour: JavaScript (and since CSS3, it should also be possible to trigger an animation that hides some div after 5000ms).

Now you have to consider:

- Should the client itself hide the alert box? (that's the most common and most easy way using jQuery)
- Should the server tell the client to hide it? (I know I said above that's not possible, but it actually is using something called `server push`, which is implemented in a library called `atmosphere` (formerly `comet`). But it's not a real message from the server, it's more a second request from the client which first gets answered by the server when there's an event to send to the client (`long-pooling`)). Notice: This also required JavaScript on the client side.

I'd say: Go with the first solution (`jQuery`) 'cause it's already built into Rails (at least if you are at Rails 3.1 or above)

Have a look here: [How to hide a div after some time period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426304/how-to-hide-a-div-after-some-time-period)