# Output message when button is clicked and then make it automatically disappear after some time

Tags: php, html, button, isset

I want to output text once a button is clicked but also have it automatically disappear within a specific time frame. Currently, I have written php code so that the message appears when the button is clicked but I am not sure how to make it automatically disappear within a given time frame. The following is the php code I have:

```
     <?php if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])): ?>
   <div class="msg">
     <?php

         echo $_SESSION['msg'];
         unset($_SESSION['msg']);
     ?>
   </div>
 <?php endif ?>
```

$_SESSION['msg] is obtained from another file and its code is shown below:

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "Data Entry Added!";
}
```

Comment: @RobinSingh what would the code look like?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4109411/13359052)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve this using jQuery.

Include [Jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) in your app

Create a message div with style display:none by default.

On button click add on click function to change content of that div with your message you can use [ajax request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) to retrieve that message from PHP.

Once you change content use javascript method to show & hide after interval

```
$('#messagediv).show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426304/how-to-hide-a-div-after-some-time-period) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(()=>{ $('.msg').hide(1000); },3000);
```

Hides class `msg` with 1s animation in 3s. Assuming you are using jquery library.